# Dialogflow CX - Transition to another page from webhook

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In Dialogflow CX, I want to use webhook to send a fulfillment response as well as transition to another page. I have tried using the following code to transition to a page called 'test' but it is not working. I am looking for a piece of code that will send a response back to agent and also transition to another page. Thank you.

```
 if(tag=='welcome'):
       fulfillmentResponse = {
            'session_info': {
                'parameters': {
                    'transition_page': "test" 
                } 
            }, 
        }
            
      return jsonify(fulfillmentResponse)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [webhookResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#webhookresponse), you can set the **`fulfillment_response`** and **`target_page`** fields to send a fulfillment response as well as transition to another page respectively. Here’s an example below:

```
{
    target_page: projects/<Project ID>/locations/<Location ID>/agents/<Agent ID>/flows/<Flow ID>/pages/<Page ID>,
    fulfillment_response: { 
        messages: [{ 
            text: [“Text response from webhook”],
        }] 
    } 
}
```

Here’s a sample result:

[image]